# Download any file from Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm a Google Drive API rookie. In my app, I integrate Google Drive Api to allows user search in its Drive folders an specific extension files (.gpx). I use newOpenFileActivityBuilder() in IntentSender, so user can pick the file he wants.

```
String[] mimeTypes = {"unknown/unknown","application/octet-stream","application/type"};

IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(mimeTypes)
            .build(gDriveclient);
```

My problem is the .gpx files are not selectable, I have tried a lot of different mime types, but none works.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the MIME type for the .gpx file.  You could find it out by looking at the MIME type in the get response: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: I get the right mime type, thaaanks @cheryl !! I didn't know the fileId, so I went to files -> list left-menu. Again, a lot of thanks for the idea!

Comment: the link I say in above post: [google drive list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: @PauGa C'mon, throw us a bone here. What's the mime type for a .gpx file?